# Paypal - It only accepts Credit card payment?

Tags: paypal

I want to create payment button which has default payment type of paypal balance. I have created subscription button. Got the button link as;

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=XXXXXX
```

When you open, it shows like this;

[image]

I want to show Paypal Checkout button only, is it possible ?

And the problem is, even I click the yellow Paypal button, it still forces to subscribe with credit card only.

[image]

How can I make it possible to pay with paypal balance ? is there any parameter to be added to the paypal button link ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the options funding as below. Please see this [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/customize-button/#multiple-button-layout) for more information.

```
funding: {
  allowed: [ paypal.FUNDING.CARD ],
  disallowed: [ paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT ]
}
```

Funding methods

When multiple funding sources are available to the buyer, PayPal automatically determines which additional buttons are appropriate to display. However, you can choose to opt in or out of displaying specific funding sources in either the horizontal or vertical layout.

Set the funding option to one of these values:
allowed: Displays the specified funding methods, if the buyer is eligible.
disallowed: Hides the specified funding methods.

Comment: Thanks. But it completely disables credit card payment as I see. Is it a way to prefer paypal balance and if it isnt eligible show credit card option ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, Paypal cannot suggest to use their service by creating an extra step for the credit card payment.

Comment: I dont want to disable credit card payment, I just want to fix why it doesnt show paypal balance payment option.

Comment: I understand but it is not possible, not even if you subscribe to the Paypal Payment Pro.

Comment: You mean on subscription buttons, paypal only accepts credit card payment ?

Comment: No I mean, you cannot do it. Even vendors who subscribes to Paypal Payment Pro (https://www.paypal.com/ca/webapps/mpp/payments-pro?gclsrc=aw.ds&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsoPSrOPe4QIVREGGCh2uTgpKEAAYASACEgKi5vD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) like us, cannot make it.

Comment: Ok, lastly, do you know why it forces to credit card payment ? Does country, or etc matters on that ?

Comment: The new law force Paypal to offer their services even for people who doesn't have a Paypal account. I think it is the GDPR who forces them. https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/account-optional

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192147/discussion-between-jonathan-gagne-and-user198989).

Answer (score 1):

For subscriptions (as opposed to one-time payments), PayPal normally *requires* a credit card funding source, since it is not expected that users will maintain a balance for the lifetime of a subscription.

Comment: Thanks for your input. And I realized that the yellow paypal button comes first if visitor connected from phone.